# How do you call routers which can combine multiple WAN connections?

Tags: router

At my workplace we have a router which has two WAN connectors which allow transparently combining two ADSL connections or one ADSL and one ISDN as fallback.

What's the name of this feature?

Comment: It really doesn't have a specific name, but sometimes you'll see "dual link" advertised.

The better Q is "What do you call a router that's unable to combine two WAN connection?"  A: "A toy"  (at least as far as serverfault/business class people are concerned, now for the superuser/home user class, it's perfectly fine)   :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can say Dual-WAN or Multi-WAN Routers, theses are not very specific features, you may have for example a juniper router on which you can make any port into the wan security zone and get them to failover.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean **load balancing** ?
If yes - on SOHO routers which usually contain linux inside - by adding 2 or more default routes ([LARTC](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html))

Answer (score 0):

It is a Dual-Wan Load Balancer Router. Try this link http://www.dlink.com.ph/products/?model=DI-LB604

I'd use this product without troubles.. it works for me...

Answer (score 0):

Related (Might be useful to someone who stumbles upon this question):

When you combine T1's in the way you have mentioned, that is called bonding.  On Cisco routers, you do this with a multilink interface.